# problem with evaluateAllForumulaCells in POI 4.0.0 and java 8.0

Tags: apache-poi

We previously were using this method in java 5.0 32 bit with poi 3.17.  when we upgraded we went to poi 4.0.0 with java 8.0 64 bit and we are getting an array index out of range exception wiht signature signature "(Lorg.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;)V" in class
   "org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator".

Not sure if that method is deprecated or something has changed.  thank you.

Comment: Raise a bug at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi and include the xls file and full java stacktrace.

Comment: Make sure you only have the latest Apache POI on your classpath, it looks like you might also have older Jars still there! See http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html for code to help you track down the old jars